# inserting in trigger oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

hey I want to prevent insert new record if the total salary is greater than 1000 , so I tried to solve this issue by using trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER totalsal
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON saltable
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    CURSOR sumsalary  IS
        SELECT SUM(sal) AS sum_salary FROM saltable;

    total                                   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    OPEN sumsalary;

    FETCH sumsalary INTO total;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('value is  ');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(total);

    CLOSE sumsalary;

    IF (total < 1000)
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('in range');
        :new.sal    := :new.sal;
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('exceed limit');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

as you can see here I used cursor to get the sum then fetch value and if condition for comparison but its not working perfectly! it insert new record even if sum salary exceed range

anyone knows how to solve such a problem.

Comment: I noticed you posted 13 questions and never accepted an answer. Did you never get a good answer or is there another reason why you never accept an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF (total < 1000)
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('in range');
        :new.sal    := :new.sal;
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('exceed limit');
    END IF;
```

Please chnage these lines bro. Looks like u have not used any exception handling process for displaying any error message to the user when the salary goes beyond 1000. and also :new.sal:=:new.sal s unwanted extra line. new.sal will always contain the latest or updated value. Hence explicit assigning of values are not required. U can change the code as given below and try it out. The belw code works fine.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER totalsal
    before INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON saltable
    FOR each row
DECLARE
    CURSOR sumsalary  IS
        SELECT SUM(sal) AS sum_salary FROM saltable;

    total                                   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    OPEN sumsalary;

    FETCH sumsalary INTO total;
    total:=total+:new.sal;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('value is'||total);

    CLOSE sumsalary;

    IF (total < 1000)
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('in range');
        Your insert statement;
        ELSE
        raise_application_error(-20022, 'Salary is beynd the limit');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Bhasker thank you appreciated , this is what i want .

Comment: Anytime bro Happy that my input has helped u :)

Comment: This will give exactly the error that Nicholas Krasnov noticed

Comment: Can u elaborate aleksej coz mutating happens in case if we use after instead of before triggers and i have handled the case which u have mentioned below. Hopefully it would be better if u could help me understand by providing me with an illustration rather than words. Thank you

Comment: Try `create table salTable(sal number)`, then compile your trigger and try `insert into saltable select 1 from dual` (as Nicholas suggested).Once you'll get the error, you'll find many answers about that in SO.

Comment: Also, why a cursor to do a simple query?

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger does not prevent the insert, but simply prints a message.
If you want to avoid inserting under some conditions, you should raise an error; for example:

```
...
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('exceed limit');
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'Sal exceeds limit');
...
```

Also, notice that if the table is empty, `SUM` will give `NULL` and this could make your checks fail.

You could even avoid the cursor; if you need to compute a `SUM` and put the result in a variable, you can simply do something like:

```
select sum(...)
into yourVariable
from ...
```

And `:new.sal:=:new.sal;` does nothing and could be removed.

And also notice the important comment by Nicholas Krasnov; trying to clarify it, if you build a row level trigger (`FOR EACH ROW`) and this trigger has to check values from other rows of the table, how should Oracle handle the case, for example, of two rows inserted in a single statement? It's possible that both rows, if inserted without the other one, match the condition, but if you insert them both, the limit is exceeded. This would lead to an error as described by Nicholas. You'll find many answers in SO about this

Comment: It should be noted that `table is mutating` error might be raised. Why I said might and not will. `before insert` trigger will not generate `table is mutating` exception when you use simple `imsert into values()` statement but the error will definitely be raised if you use `insert into select from` (even if `select` statement returns only 1 row). So either define a view and use `instead of` trigger, or compound trigger, or define a set of APIs(a stored procedure that adds new record) and perform salary check there.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I did not notice the main issue. Thanks